# Function to maximise the number of sets with the total numbers that all subsets not being repeated

Tags: python-3.x, math, graph, subset, networkx

I am trying to solve this problem in python. But I cannot find a solution. The problem is the following: I have many lists hundreds of thousands, each list contains from 1 to 16 numbers that range from 0 to N. I want to maximise the number of sets that I can pool, so that the union of the chosen subsets does not contain any repeated numbers.

For instance:

```
List1 = [2,4,1012]
List2 = [0,1,3]
List3 = [1,2]
List4 = [5,8]
```

Result: [2,4,1012], [5,8] ,[0,1,3]
If I chose List3, there can only be 2 subsets without repeating elements.

Thanks in advance

I have tried using networkX graphs, but I cannot grasp how to reduce the graph to find the optimal answer or answers.

Comment: Finding a maximal solution is probably an intractable problem. Even verifying a maximal solution may be intractable though generating one may not be. Maybe you could explain how you have been using graphs to try to solve this. In practice, this kind of problem is attacked by finding a 'good' solution, then using available resources to improve on it before having to submit the best result found so far.

Comment: I thought so. But finding a local maxima would also be valid for what I want. I thought that the lists/sets could be nodes, and edges would connect the nodes if they have common components, then it would be a matter of removing nodes to basically disconnect the entire graph.

Comment: This question from Mathematics might be of help: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4217450/294695

Comment: So your lists are nodes, and you define edges between nodes if they don't share any numbers, then you're looking for the largest subset of nodes such that every node in the subset has an edge to every other node in the subset? If that is the case, you could start with a small solution and then test each remaining unselected node until you find one that can be included and repeat iteratively. This could give you a 'good' solution, but probably not optimal.

Comment: Isn't this just the [maximum set packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_packing)?